# Using if after query mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to use insert function right after a select query but with a condition.

For example

```
SELECT A FROM B

IF(A > 0, 

INSERT INTO B (A) VALUES (20),

END)
```

When I try to run in my workbench I get syntax error: unexpected if

Is this query even possible?

Comment: Is this in a procedure? `IF` can only be used as a statement in a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO B (A)
SELECT A FROM DUAL WHERE A > 0
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e5ea/1/0)

Comment: tip: mysql doesn't require dual. `select a where ...` would work just as well.

Comment: Where is the value `20`?

Comment: like I said, "doesn't require".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query.

```
INSERT INTO B (A)
SELECT 20
FROM B
WHERE A > 0
LIMIT 1
```